# awk processing files with different extensions

Tags: csv, awk, gawk

I have to process multiple `CSV` and `TXT` files in one awk script. My cmd file on windows looks like: `gawk -f script.awk *.csv *.txt > output.file`
I'd like to use this cmd file as I don't want to always type into the command prompt whenever I want to run the script. I would like to perform different tasks with the different file types. I have tried some stuff inside the script file like `if (match(FILENAME, ".csv")) && (FNR > 1)` but none of them were working. I have about 4-5 `CSV` files and a lot of (like 1000+) `TXT` files, these are all input files. The content of the `CSV` files are all in the same schema, one column between quotes. Example:

```
"Player"
"adigabor"
```

I want to ignore the first line of all the input `CSV` files when processing them and add each record w/o the quotes into an array and after that I'd like to process the `TXT` files which I can do just fine, my problem is that I couldn't perform the different tasks with the different input file extensions in one script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be extremely useful if you told us in what way "none of them were working" so we're not just guessing but here goes anyway:

The main problem with `match(FILENAME, ".csv")` is it'll match `csv` preceded by any char anywhere in the file name. To get files that **end** in literally `.csv` you want:

```
match(FILENAME,/\.csv$/)
```

but you don't need to call a function for that:

```
FILENAME ~ /\.csv$/
```

So your script would look like:

```
FILENAME ~ /\.csv$/ {
    if ( FNR > 1 ) {
        do CSV stuff
    }
    next
}
{
    do TXT stuff
}
```

If you still can't do whatever you're trying to do then edit your question to include sample input files (at least one of each small .csv and .txt files) and expected output along with a better explanation of what you are trying to do.